# navbar-top-fixed not allowing page to scroll down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When `.navbar-fixed-top` is present, the page can't scroll vertically. When the class is removed, the page scrolls fine. [Here's a live example](http://treley.com).

I've tried removing that class and applying a fixed property to the additional class navbar-dark that I customized myself. Any fixed positioning appears to break the scrolling. Any suggestions on a solution would be greatly appreciated.

This is the line with the class applied that seems to be breaking the scrolling:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar_dark" role="navigation">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `<body>` set to `overflow:hidden;`. It's on style.css Line 35. You need to change it to `overflow:visible;` and you'll be able to scroll the page again.

**Change this:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen','sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**To this:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen','sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 2em;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be something simple like that. I'm not even sure how I did that!

Comment: You're welcome, it happens to the best of us. Please mark as correct answer.